# Using Option<T> with Diesel's Insertable trait

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have the following model:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;

use crate::schema::category;

#[derive(Debug, Identifiable, Queryable)]
#[table_name = "category"]
pub struct Category {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub parent_id: Option<i64>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "category"]
pub struct NewCategory<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub description: &'a str,
    pub parent_id: &'a Option<i64>,
}
```

and schema.rs:

```
table! {
    category (id) {
        id -> Integer,
        name -> Text,
        description -> Text,
        parent_id -> Nullable<Integer>,
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code, I get the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<i64>: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/categories.rs:15:17
   |
15 | #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<i64>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&std::option::Option<i64>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<i64>: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/categories.rs:15:17
   |
15 | #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<i64>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&'a std::option::Option<i64>`
```

What do I need to get this to work? I've looked around, but the only similar issue that I've found is when someone had more than 16 columns in their table, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `pub parent_id: &'a Option<i64>` to place the `&'a` inside of the Option: `pub parent_id: Option<&'a i64>`.

Comment: In fact, putting an `i64` behind a reference is overkill IMO. I'd just use `Option<i64>` directly.

Comment: @FrancisGagné Yup, that seems to work fine as well. However, I'm following https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/ and have no idea why they did it that way there.

Comment: Using references for strings is totally fine. The function that does the insertion doesn't need ownership of a `String`. `&str` can refer to strings on the heap or in static memory, so you can avoid putting fixed strings on the heap by using references. However, `i64` is small enough that putting it behind a reference actually makes things (imperceptibly) slower.